# How to convert below SQL query into sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

ROUND(SUM(advocate_ptsscored+satisfaction_ptsscored+issueres_ptsscored) OVER (PARTITION BY Agent_EmpId, Supervisor_EmpId, Evaluation_Year, Evaluation_Month ORDER BY Evaluation_Month)/
SUM(advocate_ptsposs  +satisfaction_ptsposs  +issueres_ptsposs)OVER (PARTITION BY Agent_EmpId, Supervisor_EmpId, Evaluation_Year, Evaluation_Month ORDER BY Evaluation_Month)*100,2) M_Quality_Score

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried and clearly explain what you are having difficulty with. Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score -1):

function sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over(element, partition_by=None, order_by=None, range_=None, rows=None)

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=over#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over